# How can I fill a DataTable from a LINQ inner joined query resultset?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datatable

I have a resultset which is selected from inner joined tables with
LINQ.  How can i can return resultset as DataTable?

```
DataProviderDataContext db = new DataProviderDataContext();

IEnumerable<DataRow> asd = (IEnumerable<DataRow>)(from dsa in (from usrAddr in db.T_USER_ADDRESSes join usr in db.T_USERs on usrAddr.USER_ID equals usr.USER_ID where usr.USER_ID == UserID select new { usr.REALNAME, usrAddr.USER_ID, usrAddr.USER_ADDRESS_ID, usrAddr.ADDRESS, usrAddr.TITLE, usrAddr.IS_DELIVERY, usrAddr.IS_INVOICE }).AsEnumerable() select dsa);

DataTable dt = asd.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `CopyToDataTable<DataRow>()` operates on an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.  You need to *shred* the returned data as outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am suprised `DataTable dt = asd.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();` does not do the job for you.

Try:

```
asd.CopyToDataTable(dt, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
```